# How would I combine FABRIK inverse kinematic results with a skeletal animation?

Tags: opengl, c++, skeletal-animation, inverse-kinematics

So, I've been working on a skeletal animation system in OpenGL/C++, and it's actually not coming along too badly. I can play animations, which I do by sending bone transform matrices to my animation shader, [as per this tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html).

Now I want to combine these animations with inverse kinematics. Seems doable!  The [FABRIK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNoX65PRehA) algorithm seems simple and computationally efficient. However, I noticed that it puts out a list of positions, not a list of local quaternions. How would I go about using this algorithm in a way that is compatible with a skeletal animation system, i.e. how do I get the calculated IK world positions to combine nicely with the 4x4 transformation matrices of my skeletal animation system's joints?

I was thinking of just combining the IK positions with each vertex position in my vertex shader, but then I don't get the blended bone positions on the CPU side. Is there a way to do this that is elegant and not a performance nightmare?

Comment: From a pair of consecutive points you can get a direction vector, and from a source direction and a target direction you can form a quaternion or matrix that rotates one to the other. Where have you run into trouble generating quaternions/matrices from the points you get as output from the FABRIK algorithm?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was really just lost on how to go from FABRIK positions to proper rotations, but I got it now, thanks!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below. :)